# Nextjs react-bootstrap Modal not opening on top of page

Tags: next.js, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

In my nextjs project, I have been trying to implement a Bootstrap Modal as a component similar to this [vertically centered code example.](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#vertically-centered)

**The project structure:**

```
components 
 - modal.js
pages
 - index.js
 - about.js
```

**From index.js I call the modal component:**

```
 <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => setModalShow(true)}>
        Launch vertically centered modal
 </Button>
 <ModalMailingList show={modalShow} onHide={() => setModalShow(false)} />
```

This results in the modal **NOT** opening in a window on top of my page, but rather toggle the modal as a div inside the page.

[Here is the working code, of the unwanted behavior.](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-tu-oj0ihk?file=/pages/index.js)

How can I implement a modal component and make it **open ON TOP of the page?**
(as in the original react-bootstrap code example)

**SOLUTION UPDATE:**

Had to add bootstrap.css to *pages/_document.js*

```
<link
href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Had to add *bootstrap.css* to *pages/_document.js*

```
<link
href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
```